# Request Policy like plugin for Internet Explorer

Tags: firefox, security, internet-explorer, plugins

I'm using Firefox with a plugin called [Request Policy](https://www.requestpolicy.com/). What it basically does is the preventing of cross site requests from the currently opened website. E.g: when I open the local news site it blocks all the facebook/twitter/googleads widgets on the site.
It is really useful in the office but not everybody likes to use Firefox.

My question is: is there a similar plugin available to Internet Explorer (8+) or Opera (10+) as well?

I already googled it but didn't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

[Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/download) does that and supports IE and Opera